# How do i configure Visual Studio Code 2 to use my company github repository URL

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, token

In VSCode 2, when I go to View -> Command Palette -> Git Clone and provide the repository URL which reads something like this -  https://github.companyname.com/repostioryfolder/abc.git,
after selecting the local folder, it opens a browser github.com and prompts me to sign in. Since I do not have an account with github.com but have an account only in my company's github repository, the login fails. How do I configure VS Code to login to my company profile using my git token?

Comment: VSCode 2, huh?.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading the GitHub desktop app. The experience to connect is easier and streamlined.

https://desktop.github.com